# malloc to an element of an "array" of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

there.

I'm trying to make a program that reads a number N of words (it ends when you type -) and print it sorted.

My problem is: I'm trying to use some kind of dynamic array of char*. It reallocate an element, but crashes when I try to create space on heap to a String (line 21).

Is it possible to fix? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORD_SIZE 11

int main()
{
        char word[WORD_SIZE];
        char **set;
        int j;
        int numberWord = 0;

        /* input */
        printf("Insert a word, or '-' to stop: ");
        fgets(word, WORD_SIZE, stdin);

        while (strcmp(word, "-\n")) {
                /* process */
                set = realloc(set, sizeof(char *) * (numberWord + 1));
                set[numberWord] = malloc(sizeof(char) * WORD_SIZE);
                numberWord++;

                /* input */
                printf("Insert a word, or '-' to stop: ");
                fgets(word, WORD_SIZE, stdin);
        }

        /* output */
        printf("\nSORTED:\n");
        for (j = 0; j <  numberWord; j++) {
                printf("%s", set[j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
        free(set);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `char **set;` --> `char **set = NULL;` 2) `set[j]` doesn't set word.

Comment: Implement @BLUEPIXY's suggestion and add `strcpy(set[numberWord], word);` before `numberWord++;`.

Comment: Thank you guys, it also worked!

It worked! Thanks! But I still have a question: in a snippet of realloc manual it says: " If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size)". It confused me. lol

Comment: What do you think it was using before `char **set = NULL;`? (attempted access of an uninitialized variable is *Undefined Behavior*) Also, never assign the result of `realloc` to the variable itself, if `realloc` fails, you lose the reference to your pointer and create a memory leak. Instead use a `tmp` pointer, e.g. `void *tmp = realloc (set, ...); if (tmp) set = tmp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to initializing `set` and copying `word`, there are a number of additional somewhat subtle issues you are missing, and that can bite you. To begin lets start with a couple of non-consequential logic issues. Rarely, if ever do you actually want to store a string with the `'\n'` dangling off the end, just remove the `newline` read and included in `word` by `fgets`, e.g.

```
        /* remove trailing '\n' */
        size_t len = strlen (word);
        if (word[len - 1] == '\n')
            word[--len] = 0;            /* overwrite with nul-byte */
```

(having `len` also gives you the ability to allocate the exact amount of memory required to hold `word`, e.g. `len + 1`)

Which also gives you the opportunity to check for your exit condition with a simple *length* and *character comparison* at this point, e.g.

```
         if (len == 1 && *word == '-')   /* test for '-' */
            break;
```

(which also means your read loop can simply be `for (;;) {...}` which will not store `"-"` as one of your words)

As noted in my comment, never directly assign the return of the pointer being reallocated. Why? If `realloc` fails, `set` is not freed and `realloc` returns `NULL` -- which you then assign to `set` losing the reference to `set` and creating a memory leak. Instead, always use a temporary pointer, e.g.

```
        /* process - validate all allocations */
        void *tmp = realloc (set, sizeof *set * (numberWord + 1));
        if (!tmp) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted - realloc.\n");
            break;
        }
        set = tmp;
```

You are allocating memory for each `word`, but failing to `free` the memory you allocate for each word. You can do this in your *output* loop if you no longer need the memory thereafter, e.g.

```
    /* output */
    printf ("\nSORTED:\n");
    for (j = 0; j <  numberWord; j++) {
        printf (" %s\n", set[j]);
        free (set[j]);          /* don't forget to free word */
    }
    free(set);                  /* free pointers */

    putchar ('\n');             /* don't use printf for single char */
```

Above you indicate your are outputting your words in `SORTED` order, but nowhere do you sort your words. The simplest way to sort the words is to create a simple comparison function for the pointers in `set` and then pass `set` to `qsort` for sorting, e.g.

```
int cmpstrings (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp (*(char * const *)a, *(char * const *)b);
}

int main (void) {
    ...
    qsort (set, numberWord, sizeof *set, cmpstrings);   /* sort */
```

Putting all the pieces together and rearranging the logic of your request for input in a more concise manner, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORD_SIZE 11

int cmpstrings (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp (*(char * const *)a, *(char * const *)b);
}

int main (void) {

    char word[WORD_SIZE] = "",
        **set = NULL;
    int j, numberWord = 0;

    for (;;) {

        /* input */
        printf("Insert a word, or '-' to stop: ");
        fgets(word, WORD_SIZE, stdin);

        /* remove trailing '\n' */
        size_t len = strlen (word);
        if (word[len - 1] == '\n')
            word[--len] = 0;            /* overwrite with nul-byte */

        if (len == 1 && *word == '-')   /* test for '-' */
            break;

        /* process - validate all allocations */
        void *tmp = realloc (set, sizeof *set * (numberWord + 1));
        if (!tmp) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted - realloc.\n");
            break;
        }
        set = tmp;

        set[numberWord] = malloc (sizeof *set[numberWord] * (len + 1));
        if (!set[numberWord]) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted - malloc.\n");
            break;
        }

        strcpy (set[numberWord], word);
        numberWord++;
    }

    qsort (set, numberWord, sizeof *set, cmpstrings);   /* sort */

    /* output */
    printf ("\nSORTED:\n");
    for (j = 0; j <  numberWord; j++) {
        printf (" %s\n", set[j]);
        free (set[j]);          /* don't forget to free word */
    }
    free(set);                  /* free pointers */

    putchar ('\n');             /* don't use printf for single char */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/dynwords
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: my
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: dog
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: has
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: fleas
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: the
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: cat
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: doesn't
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: have
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: any
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: -

SORTED:
 any
 cat
 doesn't
 dog
 fleas
 has
 have
 my
 the
```

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory, attempted to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value and finally to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it, e.g.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/dynwords
==10572== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10572== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10572== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10572== Command: ./bin/dynwords
==10572==
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: my
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: dog
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: has
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: fleas
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: the
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: cat
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: doesn't
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: have
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: any
Insert a word, or '-' to stop: -

SORTED:
 any
 cat
 doesn't
 dog
 fleas
 has
 have
 my
 the

==10572==
==10572== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10572==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10572==   total heap usage: 18 allocs, 18 frees, 402 bytes allocated
==10572==
==10572== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10572==
==10572== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10572== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm you have `freed` all memory you have allocated and that there are no errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions. There are a number of subtle changes incorporated, so if there is something you don't understand, just drop a comment below.

Comment: Wow! That's so much readable now. Thank you, mate.

I've seen a lot of ways to remove the trailing '\n' but I didn't like it (until I saw yours lol).

valgrind is very useful too. Liked it a lot. Thanks, again.

I just did not get the "(char * const *)" in cmpstrings function. Why should be used const in that function and that snippet?

Comment: That is a more proper way to dereference a double-pointer to match the `qsort` `compare` function parameter type. Remember `set` is `char **`, you must derefernce the pointers passed. You can do that as `*(char **)a` or in the more proper way to reflect the `const` nature of the pointer as `*(char * const *)a`. (dereferencing a *constant-pointer-to-pointer-to-char*)

Answer (score 1):

`realloc` requires that the memory being reallocated to have already been previously allocated ([see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)).

Try adding `set = malloc(1);` before the loop to have at least 1 byte allocated before hand.

Comment: `realloc()` will also work if the first argument is `NULL`, in which case it will allocate a new block.  You don't need to allocate with another function first.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct! Using `set = NULL` should also solve the allocation as well then.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

But I still have a question:

in a snippet of  realloc manual it says: 
"  If  ptr  is  NULL,  then  the call is equivalent to malloc(size)". 

It confused me. lol

Comment: In C, if you don't specify an initial value when declaring variables, their values will be undefined, so you have to explicitly assign `NULL` to it.

Comment: Hm, thought pointers were initialized as NULL. Thank you, again. :)